# Storing Result As Table And Query Multiple Time in PgPSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to sort a particular query's result in a way that top 2 records are selected on a particular order and rest in some other particular order.

Basically something like this

```
WITH MY_TABLE AS
(
    SELECT NEARBY_CITY_ID, CNT_USERS, DISTANCE_CITY 
    FROM MY_RELATED_CITIES 
    WHERE CITY_ID = :MYCITYID
)
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE 
ORDER BY DISTANCE 
LIMIT 2

UNION

SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE 
ORDER BY CNT_USERS, DISTANCE 
LIMIT 48;
```

But this query is not syntactically right.

Can I somehow store the Result of query used to make MY_TABLE in some Json or Array or Cursor Object and then use that as a Table later in code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using parentheses?.

```
 WITH my_table AS
(
       SELECT nearby_city_id,
              cnt_users,
              distance_city
       FROM   my_related_cities
       WHERE  city_id = :MYCITYID )
SELECT *
FROM   (
                SELECT   *
                FROM     my_table
                ORDER BY distance limit 2 ) A
UNION
      (
               SELECT   *
               FROM     my_table
               ORDER BY cnt_users,
                        distance limit 48 ) B;
```

Comment: Not The Exact Code, But Your Approach Worked.


`WITH MY_TABLE AS
(
    SELECT NEARBY_CITY_ID, CNT_USERS, DISTANCE_CITY FROM MY_RELATED_CITIES WHERE CITY_ID = :MYCITYID
)
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY DISTANCE LIMIT 2
) A
UNION
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY CNT_USERS, DISTANCE LIMIT 48
) B;`


Thanks a Lot.